# POST request to API Prestashop with Python

Tags: python, web-services, request, prestashop-1.7

I achieve to list and create products through `Prestashop API`. I want to automate a little bit the product update process in my website.

But i have an issue trying to upload the images both in create new product with image and in upload an image to a product that i create through the webservice.

I don´t see any error in my code, so i want to know if I made wrong using the Prestashop API.

My code:

```
def addNewImage(product_id):
   file = 'foto.png'
   fd = io.open(file, "rb")
   data = fd.read()
   r = requests.post(urlimg + product_id, data=data,auth=(key,""), headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
   print(r.status_code)
   print(r.headers)
   print(r.content)

Prints:

500
{'Server': 'nginx', 'Date': 'Fri, 31 May 2019 09:18:27 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=utf-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Access-Time': '1559294307', 'X-Powered-By': 'PrestaShop Webservice', 'PSWS-Version': '1.7.5.2', 'Execution-Time': '0.003', 'Set-Cookie': 'PrestaShop-30ff13c7718a401c862ad41ea4c0505f=def50200b7a8c608f3053d32136569a34c897c09cea1230b5f8a0aee977e6caac3e22bea39c63c30bfc955fe344d2cbabf640dc75039c63b33c88c5f33e6b01f2b282047bfb0e05c8f8eb7af08f2cc5b0c906d2060f92fea65f73ce063bf6d87bd8ac4d03d1f9fc0d7b6bf56b1eb152575ef559d95f89fc4f0090124630ae292633b4e08cfee38cee533eb8abe151a7d9c47ed84366a5dd0e241242b809300f84b9bb2; expires=Thu, 20-Jun-2019 09:18:27 GMT; Max-Age=1728000; path=/; domain=example.com; secure; HttpOnly', 'Vary': 'Authorization', 'MS-Author-Via': 'DAV'}

b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
\n<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   \n<errors>
        \n<error>
            \n<code><![CDATA[66]]></code>
            \n<message><![CDATA[Unable to save this image]]></message>
        \n</error>
    \n</errors>
\n</prestashop>\n'
```

I probe to use the logging library of python but only tell me this:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): midominio:443

DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://midominio:443 "POST /api/images/products/20 HTTP/1.1" 500 None
```

Also I probe to change the file config/defines.inc.php, that i read in the forum of prestashop to active debug mode but any difference.

Also I probe the library prestapyt( and prestapyt3) but don´t work with python 3 and I read that are not compatible with presta 1.7

Edit:
Display_errors, and log_errors are activated in my Plesk Panel:
[image]

But when i go to var/www/vhosts/midominio/logs/error_log

I can´t see any error referenced to php or 500 error in any line.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion...

Edit: I probe the suggestion in response, but return same error.

Comment: Can you turn on log_errors in php.ini and check your PHP error log to see what triggered the 500 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the post command if all else if working fine on the backend. `data` is used to send form data and other text data. To upload a file, you should do it like this:

```
files = {'media': open('test.jpg', 'rb')}
requests.post(url, files=files)
```

So your code translates to:

```
def addNewImage(product_id):
   file = 'foto.png'
   fd = io.open(file, "rb")
   r = requests.post(urlimg + product_id, auth=(key,""), headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}, files={ 'media' : fd })
   print(r.status_code)
   print(r.headers)
   print(r.content)
```

Comment: @Peisou upon googling I found this: https://medium.com/@altin/prestashop-webservice-unable-to-save-this-image-d1542c994e7d

Comment: thanks for your suggest, i probe it, but the image that i want to save is a png with a size of 32kb.. Change it, but same error.

Comment: I am sure this is a dumb question, but what happens if you try to save in a format other than .png?

Comment: i try with jpg too. Sorry @jeremiah i don´t see the message